# How can I modify locals in Python 2.6's pdb?

Tags: python-2.6, pdb

How can I modify local variables in `pdb` or `ipdb`?  These debuggers effectively ignore changes to existing local bindings, e.g. here's an example using ipython.

```
In [3]: def foo():
   ...:     bar = 123
   ...:     import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
   ...:     print bar
   ...:

In [4]: foo()
> <ipython-input-3-ee9873383395>(4)foo()
      3     import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
----> 4     print bar
      5

ipdb> del bar               # effect is limited too the current line
ipdb> bar                   # bar is still bound to the old value
123
ipdb> del bar; print bar    # shows it worked within the line
<function bar at 0x2b7e488>
ipdb> print bar             # but the effect goes away on the next debugger line
123
ipdb> c                     # confirmation that the binding wasn't changed
123
```

Note that directly modifying `locals()` has no effect either.

In case it matters, I'm using Python 2.6.

Background: I'm trying to debug some destructor issues and want to more explicitly control when each local is deleted to track down my bug.

**EDIT**: gave a complete standalone example.

**EDIT 2**: This is at least partially fixed in Python 2.7.  Any solutions for Python 2.6 would still be appreciated.

Comment: As you note, this is a bug in pdb in Python 2.6.  The [bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue5215) provides a patch to pdb.py that fixes it.

Comment: @BrenBam thanks, I'll see if I can get this patch applied to our installation until we can finish upgrading to 2.7.  Feel free to upgrade your comment to an answer if you want reputation for it.

Comment: I just noticed that some comments on that bug indidcate the patch isn't qute right.  Be sure to read the bug comments and follow links to other patches that might be relevant.  Another possibility is to try copying pdb.py from a Python 2.7 install.  Not sure this will work but it's worth a try.

Comment: @BrenBam: You're right; the patch doesn't cause the actual bindings to change.  It just caches them so it looks like they've changed while poking around in the debugger.